# How do I preprocess "extra fields"?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

Drupal allows you to create "*extra fields*" through [hook_field_extra-fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7).

I'd like to be able to load javascript (among other things) in my module, based on the presence of one of these fields, but I can't seem to find a hook that will fire before it renders.

I've tried *hook_preprocess_HOOK* (for mymodule_preprocess_field), but that didn't work. You can detect for it on *hook_preprocess_node*, but that doesn't work if the field is being rendered individually, or a in a view. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were saying you'd like to be able to do it when the fields were rendered individually. There's no standard way of rendering a pseudo-field individually AFAIK (you can't `field_view_field()` it) - they're normally added to an entity. Could you give an example of when it's used individually? (Also could you supply the psuedo-field code or contrib module that provides it?)

Comment: @Andy I don't have an example of rendering one individually, but I assumed it could be done (since you can render a single pseudo-field in views using something like https://www.drupal.org/project/extrafield_views_integration). If not, then your answer may cover all the use cases.

Comment: I'd never seen that project before, thanks. AFAICT it relies on the `callback` key that isn't part of the core `hook_field_extra_fields()`. (So basically it's extending core to allow extra fields to be displayed individually.)

Comment: Are you dealing with nodes or some other entity?

Comment: I'm dealing with nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what fields you are dealing with.

hook_field_extra_fields() allows you to define extra fields for any entity, then the field itself is added in a hook that runs when the entity's content is being generated.

That is the place where you need to add the js.

In that hook you can modify the fields you care about and add your js using [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) or [#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached).

#attached is generally more resilient to caching as it lives with the field render array.

Use #attached like this:

```
$form['YOURELEMENT']['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/javascript.js';
```

For example, if the field you want is being added to nodes, you would implement [hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) or [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) something like this:

```
function MODULENAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if (isset($node->content['EXTRAFIELD'])) {
    $node->content['EXTRAFIELD']['#attached']['js'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/javascript.js';
  }
}
```

or in hook_node_view_alter() it would be like this:

```
function MODULENAME_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if (isset($build['EXTRAFIELD'])) {
    // Change its weight.
    $build['EXTRAFIELD']['#attached']['js'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/javascript.js';
  }
}
```

The same principle can be applied to other entity types, like users, which would use [hook_user_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7) or [hook_user_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7).

If your field is on multiple entity types you might have to use multiple of these implementations, or even better, you could use [hook_entity_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7) or [hook_entity_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7), which allow you to target all entity types in the one place.

If you need to make sure your hook runs after all other modules' implementations of that same hook then you can either set the weight of your module higher than others or use [hook_module_implements_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to make sure your module runs last.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer (maybe I'm missing something). `hook_field_extra_fields_alter()` is not invoked to display a pseudo-field, it simply defines them (and the results are cached).

Comment: Oops sorry, you are correct it is the wrong answer. I have fixed the wrong.